# Simplifying a sum in a linear difference equation

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to solve the difference equation $y_{n+1}=y_n+2^n.$

I have done most of it and come down to the line $$y_n=y_0+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2^j$$

I'm not sure how to find an expression for this sum though. Where should I go next?

Comment: Do you know the formula for the sum of a geometric series? Apply that here - you'll get a simple result. Your answer will still be in terms of $y_0$, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}x^j = \frac{x^n - 1}{x-1}_.$$

Comment: Is it not $\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$?

Comment: That is the same thing :). Factor out a $(-1)$ on top and bottom.